# Die hard or die heart?

Tags: idioms, colloquialisms

I just saw someone write that they were a "die heart" fan. I always thought the term was supposed to be "die hard" but I decided to google it just in case I was wrong.

Google was unable to give me a definitive answer as there were folk on both sides of the fence. Anyone know the true answer?

Comment: http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/401/die-hearted/

Comment: lololol! There is a forum for movies in stackexchange, you know.

Comment: @congusbongus Right, I gathered that there are plenty of people using the term 'die heart'. Your reference makes it look like that is a variant of 'die hard' with references to when people have used it that way. So I wonder whether this is a case where people have used it the wrong way long enough that it's now considered correct?

Comment: @BVernon,  Do you recall the percentages in each instance?

Comment: @BVernon it's an [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn).

Comment: *this is a case where people have used it the wrong way long enough that it's now considered correct?* -- No. the expression is **not** correct as a substitute/synonym for *die hard*, it has its own existence as an informal 'eggcorn' with its own meaning and connotations.

Comment: @congusbongus There's a difference, though, between correctly using an eggcorn and an incorrect expression used under ignorance. There are many such errors, esp., in speech, which are not eggcorns.

Comment: But I've looked at the definitions, and I see no substantial difference between the "definitions" of "diehard" and "dieheart".

Comment: You may be interested to know that Google also finds multiple instances of _blowheart_ and _bravehard_. Clearly everything connected to spelling and compounding is in flux, and nothing is certain. Teach the controversy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think "diehard," "die hard," and "dieheart" are all different.

> diehard |ˈdīˌhärd|
>   noun [ often as modifier ]
>   a person who strongly opposes change or who continues to support something in spite of opposition: diehard traditionalists | she was a diehard Yankees fan.
>   ORIGIN mid 19th cent.: from die hard (see die1) .

"Die hard" is a phrase, not a word.

> PHRASES
>   die hard – disappear or change very slowly: old habits die hard.

"Die heart" is nonexistent in a legitimate dictionary, so all we can do is consult definitions that may have been randomly fabricated.

As Kris defined from UrbanDictionary:

> One who is ridiculously overwhelmingly passionate about a specific thing, person, place, verb, or adverb. One willing to die for said cause, and as a result their heart would stop beating.
>   She was a dieheart about the consumption of breakfast cereals. Thus meaning that she valued the consumption of breakfast cereals with great integrity.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong. I think my mistake was making it two words instead of a single one, otherwise I would have found it in the dictionary and that would have settled it :)

Answer (score 1):

***die heart***, also *dieheart*
Informal, after the expression *die hard*, esp., in contrast, not as a synonym/ variant.

See [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dieheart) *dieheart*:

> One who is ridiculously overwhelmingly passionate about a specific thing, person, place, verb, or adverb. One willing to die for said cause, and as a result their heart would stop beating.
>   *She was a dieheart about the consumption of breakfast cereals. Thus meaning that she valued the consumption of breakfast cereals with great integrity.*

*cf*. [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=die%20hard&defid=3472485)  **2**. *die hard*:

> It means when you are determined to do something, similarly like Bruce Willis in the film Die Hard.
>   Can be used as a verb or a noun.

Comment: A verb or a noun?  "He challenged us to diehard the marathon"??

Comment: @GEdgar Doesn't work as a noun either, haha.  That's what you get from urban dictionary though :)

Comment: @GEdgar Any noun can generally be 'verbed' (these days). Why blame urban dictionary?